# Any hint to solve $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ x^2 ((1+\frac{m}{x})^n-(1+\frac{n}{x})^m)$?

Tags: limits

I am stuck on this limit: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ x^2 ((1+\frac{m}{x})^n-(1+\frac{n}{x})^m)$. Not really looking for the solution per se, but rather a hint or a tip I should maybe consider?

Comment: Binomially expand

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091647/find-the-limit-of-lim-n-rightarrow-inftyn21-fracpnq-1-frac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Using Taylor expansion, we have

$$\left(1+\dfrac mx\right)^n=1+n\dfrac mx+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\dfrac{m^2}{x^2}(1+\epsilon_1(x))$$

with
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\epsilon_1(x)=0$$

You should find that the limit is
$$\dfrac{nm(n-m)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We can use that by [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

$$\left(1+\frac{m}{x}\right)^n=1+\frac{mn}{x}+\frac{n(n-1)m^2}{2x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$$